# Validate is a string is empty using Scanner and return the empty string as valid value

Tags: java, string, validation

I use Scanner in Java to get user entries such as name, surname, email and tel. The name and surname are required but the email and tel are not required and they can be leaved as empty by user just by hitting enter key.

This is the method I use to validate length of each entry and display an error message if length is under or over the lngMin or lngMax.

```
public static String validateString (String msgSoll, String msgErr, 
               int lngMin, int lngMax) {
          String myString = null;
          
          if (lngMin >= 0 && lngMax >= lngMin) {
             do {
                System.out.print(msgSoll);
                myString = myScanner.nextLine();
                if (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax) {
                   System.out.println(msgErr);
                }
             } while (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax);
          }
          return myString;
       }
```

I have this method to validate the email where I called the validateString method and other methods to validate if email contains at least 1 dot and only one @ and specials and numeric characters. In this method I want to validate if email is empty and if its the case return an empty email as valid value.

```
public static String validateEmail() {
        String email = null;
        String validEmail = null;
        boolean isAlpha = false;

            do {

                email = validateString(MSG_SOLL_COURRIEL, MSG_ERR_COURRIEL, 5, 50);

                isAlpha = Tp2Utils.isAlphaNumPlus(email, "@,.,_") && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '.') >= 1 && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '@') == 1;


                    if (isAlpha) {
                        validEmail = email;
                    }


            } while (!isAlpha);

        return validEmail;
}
```

I have this method to validate telephone where I used a method to validate if tel contains only numeric characters. In that method I also need to validate if tel is empty and if it's the case return the empty tel as valid value.

```
 public static String validateTel() {
    
            boolean telValid = false;
    
            String tel = null;
            String telVal;
    
            do {
    
                tel = validateString(MSG_SOLL_TEL, MSG_ERR_TEL, 10, 10);
    
                telValid = Tp2Utils.containsOnlyNums(tel);
    
    
            } while (!telValide);
    
            telVal = tel;
    
            return telVal;  
        }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with my validation problem.

Thank's

Comment: A validation method that returns the string being validated is not good, it should return for instance true/false to state if the string is valid or not. So separate reading from the Scanner and the actual validation into 2 methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (Thanks to [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955904/validate-is-a-string-is-empty-using-scanner-and-return-the-empty-string-as-valid/64956316#comment114839419_64956316)):**

Although adding the new parameter, `boolean mandatory` will keep the code less confusing and clean, the problem can be solved even by processing the value of `lngMin`

```
public static String validateString (String msgSoll, String msgErr, int lngMin, int lngMax) {
    String myString = null;

    if (lngMin >= 0 && lngMax >= lngMin) {
        do {
            System.out.print(msgSoll);
            myString = myScanner.nextLine();

            // Return a blank string if the min required length is 0
            if (lngMin == 0 && myString.isBlank()) {
                return myString;
            }

            if (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax) {
                System.out.println(msgErr);
            }
        } while (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax);
    }

    return myString;
}
```

Then, you call it as

```
public static String validateEmail() {
    String email = null;
    String validEmail = null;
    boolean isAlpha = false;

    do {
        email = validateString(MSG_SOLL_COURRIEL, MSG_ERR_COURRIEL, 0, 50);
        if (email.isBlank()) {
            return email;// Return blank
        }
        isAlpha = Tp2Utils.isAlphaNumPlus(email, "@,.,_") && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '.') >= 1 && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '@') == 1;
        if (isAlpha) {
            validEmail = email;
        }
    } while (!isAlpha);

    return validEmail;
}
```

**Original answer:**

You can put a boolean parameter e.g `boolean mandatory` in the method signature. If you pass `false` for this parameter, the method should return an empty string in case the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering any value.

```
public static String validateString (String msgSoll, String msgErr, int lngMin, int lngMax, boolean mandatory) {
    String myString = null;

    if (lngMin >= 0 && lngMax >= lngMin) {
        do {
            System.out.print(msgSoll);
            myString = myScanner.nextLine();

            // Return a blank string if not mandatory
            if (!mandatory && myString.isBlank()) {
                return myString;
            }

            if (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax) {
                System.out.println(msgErr);
            }
        } while (myString.length() < lngMin || myString.length() > lngMax);
    }

    return myString;
}
```

Then, you call it as

```
public static String validateEmail() {
    String email = null;
    String validEmail = null;
    boolean isAlpha = false;

    do {
        email = validateString(MSG_SOLL_COURRIEL, MSG_ERR_COURRIEL, 5, 50, false);
        if (email.isBlank()) {
            return email;// Return blank
        }
        isAlpha = Tp2Utils.isAlphaNumPlus(email, "@,.,_") && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '.') >= 1 && Tp2Utils.hasNChar(email, '@') == 1;
        if (isAlpha) {
            validEmail = email;
        }
    } while (!isAlpha);

    return validEmail;
}
```

Comment: What’s the point of adding a new parameter,the same can be achieved by calling the method with lngMin = 0?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Not, `lngMin = 0` but `lngMax = 0` can serve the purpose. However, the new parameter, `boolean mandatory` will keep the code less confusing and clean.

Comment: No, lngMax set to 0 will mean any non empty string will fail

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - You are right. I've updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = getValidatedField(in, "Enter your name: ", Validators.NAME_VALIDATOR);
        String surname = getValidatedField(in, "Enter your surname: ", Validators.NAME_VALIDATOR);
        String email = getValidatedField(in, "Enter your email: ", Validators.EMAIL_VALIDATOR);
        String phone = getValidatedField(in, "Enter your phone: ", Validators.PHONE_VALIDATOR);

        // process your validated fields here
    }

    private static String getValidatedField(Scanner in, String message, Function<String, ValidationResult> validationRule) {
        ValidationResult validationResult;
        String input;
        do {
            System.out.println(message);
            input = in.nextLine();
            validationResult = validationRule.apply(input);
            System.out.println(validationResult.getMessage());
        } while (!validationResult.isSuccess());
        return input;
    }
}

class Validators {
    private static final String WRONG_LENGTH_MSG = "Invalid length.";
    private static final String WRONG_FORMAT_MSG = "Wrong format.";
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "(^$|^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[A-Za-z]+$)";
    private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "^[A-Za-z ,.'-]*$";
    private static final String ONLY_NUMBERS_PATTERN = "^[0-9]*$";

    private static boolean checkMinMaxLength(final String input, int min, int max) {
        int length = input.length();
        return length < min || length > max;
    }

    public static Function<String, ValidationResult> NAME_VALIDATOR = input ->
    {
        final ValidationResult result;
        if (checkMinMaxLength(input, 1, 10)) {
            result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_LENGTH_MSG);
        } else if (!input.matches(NAME_PATTERN)) {
            result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_FORMAT_MSG);
        } else {
            result = ValidationResult.success();
        }
        return result;
    };

    public static Function<String, ValidationResult> PHONE_VALIDATOR = input ->
    {
        final ValidationResult result;
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
            if (checkMinMaxLength(input, 2, 11)) {
                result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_LENGTH_MSG);
            } else if (!input.matches(ONLY_NUMBERS_PATTERN)) {
                result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_FORMAT_MSG);
            } else {
                result = ValidationResult.success();
            }
        } else {
            result = ValidationResult.success();
        }
        return result;
    };

    public static Function<String, ValidationResult> EMAIL_VALIDATOR = input ->
    {
        final ValidationResult result;
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
            if (checkMinMaxLength(input, 4, 20)) {
                result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_LENGTH_MSG);
            } else if (!input.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN)) {
                result = ValidationResult.failure().message(WRONG_FORMAT_MSG);
            } else {
                result = ValidationResult.success();
            }
        } else {
            result = ValidationResult.success();
        }
        return result;
    };


    private Validators() {
    }
}

class ValidationResult {
    private static final String OK_MSG = "OK";
    private final boolean success;
    private String message;

    public ValidationResult(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public ValidationResult(boolean success, String message) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static ValidationResult success() {
        return new ValidationResult(Boolean.TRUE, OK_MSG);
    }

    public static ValidationResult failure() {
        return new ValidationResult(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    public ValidationResult message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful, please add an explanation of your solution